# ref in 2nd useEffect was not showing update from 1st useEffect

Tags: react-hooks

Here is my React Native 0.68 function component with 2 useEffect:

```
export default MyComp = ({ navigation, route}) => {
  const _ref = useRef({});

  //1st useEffect
  useEffect(()=> {
    let cb = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
    _ref.current = cb;  //in async way which are not showing here
  }, [var1,var2]);

  //2nd useEffect
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(`${_ref.current.a} ${_ref.current.b}, ${_ref.current.c}`);
  },[]);
}
```

My understand is that 1st useEffect is always executed before the 2nd and `console.log` in 2nd useEffect shall output `1,2,3`. However what the actual console output is `undefined, undefined, undefined`. What is missing here and how to pass the value of cb to inside of 2nd useEffect?

Comment: You're arguments var1, var2 doesn't exist?

Comment: var1 and var2 are state defined in the component.

Comment: Here is what I learned after some test: 1. sync code in useEffect is executed in the order of its written. 2. finish time of async code depends on its complexity and do not following order of its written.  Complex async code may start earlier but finish later.

Comment: @gorzk: I have rejected your edit. Code formatting on software/library names is not appropriate, and this post does not need any bold.